# ovs flow rule for multiple IP-Address source

Tags: openflow

I have a station that I need to map a multiple IP-Address:Port to same host. For example; host1 10.11.2.9:80 can be exposed to vip1 10.107.140.192:8800 and vip2 192.168.30.12:31801. The below flow rules show the IP mapping.

```
cookie=0x0, duration=8899.921s, table=0, n_packets=16, n_bytes=1184, priority=100,tcp,nw_dst=10.107.140.192,tp_dst=8800 actions=mod_dl_dst:72:33:3d:ba:b1:8b,mod_nw_dst:10.11.2.9,mod_tp_dst:80,output:vethc803d85e
cookie=0x0, duration=8899.921s, table=0, n_packets=21, n_bytes=1397, priority=100,tcp,nw_dst=192.168.30.12,tp_dst=31801 actions=mod_dl_dst:72:33:3d:ba:b1:8b,mod_nw_dst:10.11.2.9,mod_tp_dst:80,output:vethc803d85e
```

My problem when I set the opposite flow rule to send the traffic back as below

```
cookie=0x0, duration=8899.921s, table=0, n_packets=14, n_bytes=1259, priority=100,tcp,nw_src=10.11.2.9,tp_src=80 actions=mod_dl_src:72:33:3d:ba:b1:8b,mod_nw_src:192.168.30.12,mod_tp_src:31801,NORMAL
```

How can I distingush in the opposite flow rule between the destinations IP-Address ?

Comment: This depends on your application logic...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether the question is still relevant.
IMO you have to implement the FIB (routing table) in OVS.
For example, if the 2 VIF interfaces were regular IP interfaces, how would the OS determine via which interface? According to the routing table, for example:

```
$ip r
0.0.0.0/0 via 10.107.140.254 dev eth0
10.107.140.0/24 dev eth0
192.168.30.0/24 dev eth1
```

According to the OVS [documentation](http://pleiades.ucsc.edu/doc/pica8/ovs-commands-reference.pdf), you can add OF rules to match DST IP with mask:

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow <bridge> dl_type=<ethernet type>,nw_dst=ip[/netmask],actions=<action>
```

Therefore, you need to add at least 3 rules (local subnet of VIF1, local subnet of VIF2, default gateway), similar to the output of `ip r` above.